# How to make slider of div's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I visited a website http://www.printvenue.com and at the bottom of the **print venue** page there is a heading **Top Seller** and there I saw division's were changing on interval. As I have seen that in so many sites but I was always wondering how to do that. Can anybody tell me how can I make division's like that ?

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this jQuery plugin before which is quite good http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Or it would be quite easy to code something yourself, using jQuery's .animate() to make the div's move and javascript .setInterval() to trigger the animation

Answer (score 0):

That's a JavaScript carousel. You can make your own, but there are also a lot of jQuery plugins for the same techniques. http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/